# Inline validation scrolling to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

I am using jquery inline validation plugin:
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

here:

http://bybyweb.com/mealbook/user/add

If you test this page (by clicking upload at the bottom), on lower screen resolutions (less than 1680x1050), you will notice strange scrolling to the left hand side (scroll top is default, normal behavior)... i have used this plugin before, and i've never had similar problems...

something is probably wrong in my html/css structure. If you have idea what could it be - please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take away `body{overflow-x: hidden;}` you can see at the smaller window sizes the page has extra space to the right. This extra space is caused by having set widths that are larger than their containers in the `#header`.

1. In your `#header` you set the width of `#logo_main_menu` to `940px`. This means that all the child elements need to add up to 940px.
2. Inside that div you set a width of `272px` on `#logo` and `705px` on `#search`. They add up to a total of `977px` not `940px`!
3. To make things worse inside `#search` you set the width of the `#menu` to `940px`, which means actually you now are trying to fit `940 + 272 = 1212px` into a space that you have set as `940px`.
4. I am sure there are other elements within `#search` that have fixed widths too.

**To sum it up, you need to make sure that if you use fixed pixel widths they all add up to the width of the parent container, in this case 940px**

p.s. I tested removing those widths and the scroll seemed to work well. No sideways motion. At even smaller widths it starts to look a bit odd again. To fully test you need to make sure `body{overflow-x: hidden;}` is turned off and that all of your widths add up to their container.